# HttpErrorResonse Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0 Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-functions, httprequest

I'm using google firebase cloud functions.

When accessing my cloud function from client, I get the below HttpError

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:13445:51)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:13121:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:71621:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:13120:40)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12888:51)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:13203:38)
    at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:14361:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:14398:25)

text: "Sended"
```

Below is my server code,

```
exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
      .....
      return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
        if (erro) {
          return res.send(erro.toString());
        }
        return res.send('Sended');
      });
    })
  });

});
```

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: res.send appears to be expecting json rather than string 'Sended'

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code like this:

```
exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
    .....
        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
            if (erro) {
                return res.status(500).json({"message":erro.toString()});
            }
            return res.status(200).json({"message":"Sent"})
        });
    })
});
```

It's a good practice to specify HTTP status codes in the response of your requests and also send standard JSON data through it. 
I myself always send a "message" field for such requests.